# Rails cycle helper with a few exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, cycle, alternating

I'm using the Rails `cycle()` helper method in the standard way with table rows to make alternating rows different background colors. However, I want an occasional row or two (that match certain criteria) to be a different, third color, without interrupting the cycle.

In other words, I want rows like:

```
white
black
red
black
white
black
white
```

Instead of:

```
white
black
red
white
black
white
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got to store it in a temporary variable and make the call to cycle() to ensure it is up-to-date.

```
<%
class = cycle('white', 'black', :name => 'colors')
class = 'red' if should_be_highlighted
%>
<tr class="<%= class %>">
```

You could wrap this up nicely in your own helper.

Comment: NB using `class` as variable name bad practice in most languages